# Prevent Android keyboard scrolling the screen

Tags: javascript, android, html, jqtouch

I have a webapp that has an `input` at the top of the screen. As soon is it comes `infocus` the keyboard pops up and pushes the field of the screen. Below the field is a map so trying to drag the screen down only drags the map.

I have tried the following

```
  $('#searchTextField').bind('focus',function(event){
      setTimeout(function() {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          document.body.scrollTop = 0;
          },1500);
   });
```

I added a slight delay as scrolling immediately only seemed to work for an instant. The delay does bring half the field into view but just bounces back up again. Each time I enter a letter in the field the screen scrolls up further with each letter.

Is there a way to prevent the screen for scrolling at all as the height will never change.

[image: screen]